# React Native Calendar returns {"_U":0,"_V":0,"_W":null,"_X":null}, not awaiting a promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, expo

I am using expo-calendar and retrieving an object of calendars from a user's device.

After receiving the calendars I am using the calendar to retrieve the events from the individual calendars.

Upon requesting for the events I am receiving `{"_U":0,"_V":0,"_W":null,"_X":null}` when I log the requested event data.

Along with this I am receiving the error: `` [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: An exception was thrown while calling `ExpoCalendar.getEventsAsync` with arguments `(] at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:103:50 in promiseMethodWrapper at node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23 in moduleName.methodInfo.name at http://127.0.0.1:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:321320:82 in getEventsAsync$ at Screens/Tasks_1.js:1018:15 in <global> ``

I believe this is because the request `const events = Calendar.getEventsAsync()`   is waiting on a promise but I cannot determine what response it is waiting for. How can I correctly access the events?

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
//REQUEST PERMISSION TO ACCESS CALENDAR
      const { status } = await Calendar.requestCalendarPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const calendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync(
          Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT
        );
//LIST OF ALL CALENDARS ON DEVICE WITH ID's
        console.log("Here are all your calendars:");
        console.log({ calendars });
//GET EVENTS FROM A CALENDAR ON DEVICE WITH A GIVEN ID AND TIME RANGE
        const events = Calendar.getEventsAsync(
          calIDs,
          "2021-04-14T17:00:00.00Z",
          "2021-09-14T17:00:00.00Z"
        );
//THIS LOGS {"_U":0,"_V":0,"_W":null,"_X":null}
        console.log("EVENTS" + JSON.stringify(events));
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Isn't `const events = await Calendar.getEventsAsync`?

Comment: Why do you call `then` just as is and do nothing inside it? You should be using the callback's result inside `then` OR using await, but not both.

Comment: that was a typo I edited it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{"_U":0,"_V":0,"_W":null,"_X":null} this is happen probably because you didn't add **await** keyword before **Calendar.getEventsAsync** !!

Comment: when I use await this seems to solve this issue requested but then I receive `ExpoCalendar.getEventsAsync` with arguments `(]......could this be because of the aruments sent?

Comment: what do you mean by you receive <<ExpoCalendar.getEventsAsync with arguments `(]>> ,could you give the whole error or add it as an edit in your question

Comment: I added the entire error into the body of the question

Comment: is this something that could be cause due to how expo-calendar was installed?

Comment: @Ikhadir I resolved the other issue thanks!