# async/await not working, function returning {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I have tried other similar questions on StackOverflow but I found no solution to my problem.

Problem is that I am making an API call inside a function, I am also using async/await for this call but the function still returning {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69456559/13767516) and other questions on StackOverflow, I came to know that this problem arises because the function not working properly with API.

```js
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

async function userLogin(name, password) {
    await firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("name", "==", name).where("password", "==", password).get()
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Response:')
            if (response.docs === []) {
                return
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
}

const initialState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    name: '',
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'LogIn') {
        const data = userLogin(action.name, action.password)
        if (data) {
        return {
            ...state,
            name:action.name,
            loggedIn:false
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log(4);
            return {
                ...state,
                name: 'aName',
                loggedIn:true
            }
            }
    }
    return state;
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: `userLogin` returns a promise. `data` contains a promise. I think, you can't use asynchronous functions in a reducer.

Comment: In addition to @jabaa's comment, try calling userLogin func outside reducer and on the success resposne dispatch the Login action

Answer (score -1):

userLogin not return anything in your code. Try:

```
async function userLogin(name, password) {
  return await firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("name", "==", name).where("password", "==", password).get()
  ...
```

To be precise, according to jabaa comment, userLogin returns null wrapped in Promise, which looks like

> {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

Try add return and then check data constant. That give you response from firestore method.

Comment: _"Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Yes, thats true, but if you don't set returned value, it will response with null wrapped in promise, like in your case: {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}. Thats why const data = userLogin(action.name, action.password) setting 'data' to nulled promise instead firebase method response.

Comment: But your answer is wrong: _"userLogin not return anything in your code"_. `userLogin` returns a promise. Your answer won't fix the problem. `data` is still a promise.`if (data)` won't work.